# How to extract specific values from a file and print them into another file

Tags: bash, perl

I have PDB files that are named by their PDB ID, for instance `2KRJ.pdb`. I want to extract from them only the lines that begin with `ATOM` or `HETATM`, and copy them into a new file with the same name and a `.txt` extension, for instance `2KRJ.txt`.

I know how to extract those lines but I am having trouble copying them to another file.

This is the script that I have written so far for extracting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$dirname = '.';
opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "cannot open directory";
@files = grep(/\.pdb$/,readdir(DIR));

foreach $files ( @files ) {

    open (FH, $files) or die "could not open $files\n";
    @file_each = <FH>;
    #print @file_each;
    #print "$file\n";
    close FH;

    #$dir_sz = scalar @files;
    #print "$dir_sz\n";
    close DIR;

    my @ac        = ();
    my @dr        = ();
    my @os        = ();
    my @names     = ();
    my @ion_names = ();
    my $flag      = 0;

    for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#file_each; $line++ ) {  # loop reading each line from the @file up to the end of file  

        chomp( $file_each[$line] );

        if ( $file_each[$line] =~ /^HEADER/ ) {

            my @id       = split '\s+', $file_each[$line];
            my $filename = pop @id;
            $filename    = "$filename.pdb";

            while ( $file_each[$line] !~ /^END/ ) { # read the lines until you get the symbol 'END'

                $line++;

                if ( $file_each[$line] =~/^ATOM|^HETATM/ ) {

                    $file_each[$line] =~ s/^ATOM|^HETATM//;

                    @xyz = split '\s+', $file_each[$line];
                    chomp @xyz[0,6,7,8];
                    print join (':', @xyz), "\n";

                    push @coord, @xyz[0,6,7,8];
                    print "@coord\n";
                }

                open (OUTPUT, ">$filename.txt"); 
                print(OUTPUT "@coord\n"); 
                close OUTPUT;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this script does not print the first column and the output is a bit disorganised, there are no four column of each row.

Lines that I am trying to extract look like this:

```
ATOM    946  OH  TYR A  59      37.734  36.478  24.541  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM    947  H   TYR A  59      33.478  35.320  18.896  1.00  0.00           H
```

And I am trying to change it so that the new text file script contains only this:

```
ATOM   37.734  36.478  24.541          
ATOM   33.478  35.320  18.896
```

But I am getting this

```
 .326 2.859  229 -18.940 4.490  230 -23.744 0.422  230 -24.558 -0.785  230  
 -24.256 -1.547  230 -23.137 -2.012  230 -24.338 -1.681  230 -25.135 -2.969   
 230 -26.307 -2.940  230 -24.589 -4.016  230 -22.773 0.364  231 -25.257   
-1.661  231 -25.103 -2.360  231 -26.141 -3.471  231 -27.309 -3.282  231   
-25.252 -1.396
```

Comment: If your mentioning "the first column" is located just after ^ATOM or ^HETATM, it will be found in $xyz[0], not $xyz[1].  You may want to say @xyz[0, 5, 6, 7] instead.  Try to insert a code: `print join(':', @xyz), "\n";` just after the split() line to observe which is stored where.

Comment: Your code is only matching `HEADER` lines and you don't show any if those in your sample data...

Comment: Where are the HEADER line and END line?  Please show your minimal but symptom-reproduceable data with according result.

Comment: Each file starts with `HEADER` line and ends up with `END` line, I am reading each file from start to the end, I have only used `HEADER` to pop last element of the line that starts with `HEADER` and to use this to name each file. However I am matching those lines that start with `ATOM` and `HETATM` in each file.

Comment: First, do not remove the ATOM or HETATM words from the line with s/// operator. The leading whitespace remains and may be harmful to split().  Make use of indices to control which columns to keep or not.  Next, do not push \@xyz to \@coord.  Print them out immediately.  You may need to "line-by-line" processing custom.  It is a unpreferable manner to store everything in a single array because you will lose punctuations of data.

Comment: You can't write working software by copying a likely-looking program from somewhere else and hacking it at random until it works. You clearly aren't skilled enough to understand the code yourself, and it's inappropriate to ask strangers on the internet to fix it for free. You should employ a software engineer, just as you would with any other job that you were unable to complete yourself.

Comment: @tshiono: What do you mean by *"you will lose punctuations of data"*?

Comment: @Borodin: Just wanted to say the posted script merges every columns into an array without separating by lines.

Comment: @tshiono: The array contains one line of text per array element. What more separation do you want? Oh, I see, you mean the `@code` array? The only problem there is that it is never emptied. `push @coord, @xyz[0,6,7,8]` should be just `my @coord = @xyz[0,6,7,8]`.

Comment: @Borodin: I mean \@coord keeps every columns without line separations.  That is why the output is not _organized_. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: @Borodin: Okay, then only the last line will be printed out won't it?  The open() and print() may have problem in terms of their position.

Comment: @tshiono: Yes, but that's a separate issue. There are too many errors to fix in an ordinary comment, and the code is trash anyway so it needs redesigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you ask

Do you see how trying to hack an existing program leads you to write way too much code, and so increase the chances of a bug? Please learn to program in Perl and stop relying on freebies from generous souls

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

for my $pdb ( glob '*.pdb' ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $pdb;
    my $out_fh;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless my @fields = split;

        if ( $fields[0] eq 'HEADER' ) {
            open $out_fh, '>', "$fields[-1].txt";
        }
        elsif ( $fields[0] eq 'ATOM' or $fields[0] eq 'HETATM' ) {

            unless ( $out_fh ) {
                warn qq{No ID found for file "$pdb"};
                last;
            }

            print $out_fh "@fields[0,6,7,8]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
ATOM 15.200 27.271 13.911
ATOM 15.336 27.312 15.415
ATOM 16.364 26.299 15.932
ATOM 16.167 25.081 15.787
ATOM 14.019 26.968 16.088
ATOM 14.198 27.038 17.607
ATOM 13.515 25.568 15.575
ATOM 14.524 28.415 18.088
ATOM 17.456 26.771 16.532
ATOM 18.424 25.815 17.028
ATOM 19.122 26.165 18.302
ATOM 19.066 27.314 18.764
...
```

Comment: I am in the proccess of learning but it seems that I am trying to do some stuff that are above my current knowledge of perl. Problem I have is that I don't have anybody to ask something that I don't know. Anyway, will stick to the smaller tasks, and when I feel more comfortable I will move..

Comment: I found the way how to do it in bash by following command : `for i in *pdb; do awk '{ if ($1 =="ATOM"|| $1=="HETATM") print $0}' $i > $ {i||.pdb/}.txt.pdb; done`. But I wanted it in perl. Thank You and all the best.